# Is $x/x$ equal to $1$

Tags: divisibility

My question is whether $x/x$ is always equal to $1$. I am mostly intersted in real numbers and particularly wonder whether $x/x$ is defined at $x=0$.

On one hand the division should simplify to $1$, on the other hand you should not be allowed to divide by zero.

I have been trying to find whether the simplification 'goes first' or whether the division causes trouble first, but it has proven impossible for me to find usefull search terms.

---

Note that this question arose after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23763266/983722) and its first comment.

Comment: What is the value of $\frac{2x}{x}$ everywhere except 0? What "should" the value then be? The limit gives you exactly this. The value you "should" get. But the expressions which approach $\frac{0}{0}$ can have multiple values so it is undefined.

Comment: How do you interpret the string of symbols $x/x$? If you interpret it as denoting a rational function, that rational function is the constant $1$ and can be evaluated without problem at $0$. If you interpret it as a fraction of two real numbers, you have a problem at $0$.

Comment: When $x$ is non-zero member of field then $x/x=1$ follows from axioms of Field. I believe this is the case in other algebraic structures when it is zero. Basically the division $/$ or the number $1/x$ is only defined on non-zero numbers. So what happens when $x$ is zero is out of question.

Comment: @05storm26 Do you mean that division goes before simplification?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, simplification and division are not distinct processes. Simplification is simply a question of applying division to the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to ask if functions like $3+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}$ or $4+\log{x}-\log{x}$ are defined for negative $x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Its limits exist from the left and from the right at $0$, but it is not defined at $0$. It doesn't matter if you "simplify" first and then "check" or the other way around, because as you pointed out you're not allowed to divide by $0$. Thus 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \neq 0 \\ \text{undefined} & x = 0\end{cases}.$$
Consider the same question,
$$g(x) = \frac{x^2 - 2x + 1}{x-1}.$$
What is this function?

Answer (score 7):

For any real number $x\neq0$, $$x=x,$$$$\Leftrightarrow$$$$\dfrac{x}{x}=1.$$
$x=0$ $\Rightarrow x=x,$ but now we cannot divide by $x$. (Why?)

In fact, this is an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Suppose that, $\dfrac{0}{0}=\color{red}{1}$. Hence, $0=\color{red}{1}\cdot0$.

Therefore, $\color{red}{2}\cdot0=\color{red}{1}\cdot0$ since $\color{red}{2}\cdot0=0$.

So, $\color{red}{\dfrac{2}{1}}=\dfrac{0}{0}$.

Thus $\color{red}{2}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I'm assuming $x\in R$ in this whole post.

Indeed $x/x$ is only defined when $x\ne 0$. And wherever it is defined, its value is $1$.

However when people (especially in fields other than mathematics where mathematics is used) talk about such expressions, often what they *really* mean is: "The continuous (or, more generally, "well-behaved") function determined by the values of the given expression where that expression is defined". And there exists indeed exactly one continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ so that $f(x)=x/x$ for $x\ne 0$, and that is the constant function $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

As a concrete example, consider the function $\sin(x)/x$ which appears in physics in the amplitude of a wave when describing diffraction on a slit. This expression is clearly not defined at $x=0$. However is is of course silly to assume that the amplitude of a wave is not defined at some point. What physicists actually mean is the continuous function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x }{x} & x\ne 0\\
1 & x=0
\end{cases}$$
But usually that function isn't written that way; the interpretation is implicitly assumed.

Answer (score 0):

"On one hand the division should simplify to 1, ..."

No it does not: When you divide something by x (which is what you do in your simplification if you think about it) it is undefined for x=0. So when you simplify correctly you will also have the answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with all answers I've seen here, on the internet and even at MIT. What if you have $x^2 \le 4x^3 + 5x^2$. To solve you can divide both sides by $x^2$ which gives you $1 \le 4x + 5 \Rightarrow -4 \le 4x \Rightarrow -1 \le x$. But now since you divided by a power of $x$ to solve it you suddenly can't have $x = 0$ any more? It is inconsistent. I believe in simplifying instantaneously before division occurs.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the solution to $x^2\le 4x^3+5x^2$. From that inequality, we can deduce that EITHER $x\not=0$ and $1\le 4x+5$, OR $x=0$ - that is, it splits into *cases*, each of which is handled separately. The former case leads to the solution "$x\not=0$ and $x\ge -1$," and the latter case leads to the solution "$x=0$" (since $x=0$ satisfies the original equation); combining these gives the full solution, $x\ge -1$.

Comment: You do _not_ need to divide by $x^2$ to solve that. Subtracting $x^2$ is a fine first step, and is valid regardless of what value $x$ is. \begin{align} x^2&\leq4x^3+5x^2\\0&\leq4x^3+4x^2\\0&\leq4x^2(x+1)\end{align} Equality holds at $x=0$ and $x=-1$. The right side is positive on $(-1,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.

Comment: When you say "you suddenly can't have x = 0 any more?" it sheds light on what you are misunderstanding. No one is saying that in the way you are interpreting it. If you choose to divide by $x^2$, no one is saying that $x$ cannot be $0$ as a solution to the original inequality. They are saying that _either_ $x=0$ (which is obviously a solution to the original inequality) _or_ $x\neq0$ _and_ then the result of the division is valid.

Comment: I appreciate all of the responses! Will digest it. Had a "heated" discussion about this with the family when trying to help my son with his homework. still struggling but will review the comments. Truly appreciate it.

Comment: Consider instead the inequality $x^2\le -x^2$. Clearly that inequality is fulfilled by $0$ (but by no other number). Now divide both sides by $x^2$. You get $1\le -1$ which is never true, no matter what value you choose for $x$.

Comment: Perhaps it may help to split into the two cases (x=0 and x≠0) _first_?  If x=0, then the inequality is trivially true; or if x≠0, then you can divide by it, etc.

Answer (score -2):

As linked to in the post you link to, $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form - that is, there is no answer at all. It's particularly curious because it's an example of both $\frac{x}{x}$ and $\frac{y}{x}$, the former of which equals $1$ when $x\neq0$ and the latter of which has a limit that tends to either positive or negative infinity when $y\neq0$ as $x$ tends to 0.

Comment: If I read the linked answer it actually states that the value is 1. Do you mean that the answer on SO is incorrect?

Comment: Surely one cannot say $\frac{y}{0}$ tends to infinity. Using traditional arithmetic this is not defined no matter the $y$ so it cannot tend to anything.

Comment: I think it is bad to write "tends to infinity" for $\frac{y}{0}$. The existence of $\frac{y}{0}$ is at sake. You should define what is "tends to $\infty$ " and $\frac{y}0$ leads to that definition.

Comment: @boywholived, correspondingly fixed. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, the answer you link explains why MATLAB evaluates $f(0)$ as $1$ when defining $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$. It is not saying that $\frac{0}{0}=1$.